# Linear combination of normal distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, linear-transformations, normal-distribution

> The distribution of independent random variables X and Y are $X\sim \mathcal{N}(24,2^2)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(25,3^2)$. Find the distribution of $2X-Y$ and $\mathbb{P}[X-Y<40]$.

I am doing self studying and I just reached the topic Working with normal distribution on the chapter Linear combinations of random variables and I came to this topic and am stuck I don't really know what to do. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an important fact that a linear span of INDEPENDENT normally distributed random variables is still normally distributed.

For your case, let $Z=2X-Y$, then $Z$ is normally distributed with mean $E[Z]=2E[X]-E[Y]$ and variance $\mbox{Var}(Z) = \mbox{Var}(2X)+\mbox{Var}(-Y)$.

However, it is important to point out that if the given normally distributed random variables are NOT independent, their linear combination needs not be normally distributed.

Comment: i see but the answer to 2X-Y is equal to 12 and  ℙ[−<40] to 0.000442 but I do not know how to get to it

Comment: $X-Y$ is also normally distributed, whose mean and variance can be computed directly.

Comment: what does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

The critical results you need are that if $X,Y$ are independent normal random variables and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, then $aX+bY$ is also normal (note that the parameters will depend on the constants $a,b$). You can prove this using characteristic functions, for example, and then you will know how to change the parameters.

Your problem becomes an exercise applying the above statements. Can you finish it?

**UPDATE**

To estimate the first parameter, let $Z = aX+bY$ then
$$\mathbb{E}[aX+bY] = x\mathbb{E}[X] + b\mathbb{E}[Y]$$

Can you now do this for the variance, and plug the numbers from your problem?

**UPDATE 2**

You are right. We define $Z = 2X-Y$ then $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(m,s^2)$ with
$$
m = \mathbb{E}[Z] = \mathbb{E}[2X-Y] = 2\mathbb{E}[X] - \mathbb{E}[Y]
  = 2\cdot 24 - 25 = 23.
$$
For the variance, you get
$$
s^2 = \mathbb{Var}[Z] = \mathbb{Var}[2X-Y] = 2^2 \mathbb{Var}[X] + (-1)^2\mathbb{Var}[Y],
$$
so now you can complete the arithmetic and you know the distribution of $Z=2X-Y$.

To compute $\mathbb{P}[X-Y<40]$, you can transform it similarly using $V = X-Y \sim (\mu, \sigma^2)$ into the standard normal since $(V-\mu)/\sigma$ is standard normal.

Can you complete this now?

Comment: I wish I could say yes but because I have tried so many different things I have completely blanked out. could you help me.

Comment: @maryjames please see the update, please write what you are doing and where you are getting stuck exactly

Comment: okay so we have 2(24)-24 and then we get 23 then what? is this even right? all I know is that 2X-Y is equal to 12 and ℙ[−<40] to 0.000442 but I do not know how to get to it

Comment: @maryjames see another update

Comment: You are so helpful and really appreciate it but I don't know why I am so confused I did the whole 1-Ø(0-25/square root of 25) but I think that's wrong I don't know what to do.

Comment: 2X-Y is not 12. 2X-Y is a random variable that has a normal distribution with mean 23 and variance 25.

Comment: For the other question, X-Y is normal with mean -1 and variance 13.  The new random variable $\frac{X-Y-(-1)}{\sqrt{13}}$ is normal with mean 0 and variance 1. So, the probability that X-Y is less than 40 is the same as the probability a standard normal random variable is less than $\frac{40-(-1)}{\sqrt{13}}$.